# Can Regular polygon block a circle?

Tags: circles, polygons

I wondered:
 if every regular polygon can be blocked inside of a circle, Can a circle be blocked inside every regular polygon?
I don't have a history of what I have tried because I really didn't know what is the right approach in solving such problem.
 In addition the results I got online weren't satisfing enough.
Thanks.

Comment: Every regular polygon with $n$ sides gives rise to $n$ isosceles triangles and the concentric circumferences of equal radii respectively to the sides and heights of said triangles, answer with the affirmative to your problem. Regards..

Comment: What does "blocked" mean?

Comment: @lhf so all of it's vertices touch the circle